# Hypothetically, what would a new school of Islam require besides scholars, followers, and recognition?

Tags: madhhab

A friend told me once, while joking, that we should start one. I though about it since, and there seems to be no regulation whatsoever about it. Schools have been founded all throughout history. Is there something else I should know if I wanted to start one?

Comment: Umm...a methodology?

Comment: A methodology and well defined osol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Islamic_jurisprudence (based on this methodology)

Comment: Having "recognition" on the list implies a need for it to be accepted by some group of people.  Who are these people?  And why are their opinions important if you're starting a *new* school of thought?